# Firefox suddenly showing focus outline after clicking. How can I avoid outline after click but leave it for keyboard focus?

Tags: css, firefox, svelte

I am using Firefox 75.0 on Windows 10 and from today on my  buttons get a dotted outline after being clicked.
As far as I can tell I am using the same Firefox version as yesterday and I didn't change anything on my code but the outline after beeing clicked is new.

here is a snipped from my svelte code using `<Link>` from svelte-routing (for styling I am using materialize-css with some custom changes):

svelte:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <Link {to}>
    <span class="icon-button">
      <i class="material-icons icon-button">{icon}</i>
    </span>
  </Link>
</li>
```

rendered HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item svelte-l3ibn0">
  <a href="/" aria-current="page">
    <span class="icon-button svelte-l3ibn0">
      <i class="material-icons icon-button svelte-l3ibn0">home</i>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

overwriting materialize-css for custom styling:

```
 .nav-item {
    width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .icon-button {
    --button-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
    width: var(--button-size);
    height: var(--button-size);
    background-color: #484a4d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: filter 300ms;
  }

  .icon-button:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.2);
  }

  .icon-button i {
    fill: var(--text-color);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
```

and this is what it looks like -
[Not clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE2bC.png), [after I clicked it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3yBy.png)

I am just learning svelte and I am fairly new to frondend development. I may be missing something simple.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably Firefox adding an outline to your links on focus/active. You can remove it by setting outline to none:

```css
.nav-item a {
  outline: 0;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try to reset it like this:

```css
.nav-item a,
.nav-item a:focus,
.nav-item a:active {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Just have in mind you can cause issues for people navigating the web with a keyboard, here's [more info about it](https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/).

Comment: This "works", but I want to keep the outline if someone uses TAB to focus the link. This way there is no outline at all. I just don't want it after I clicked the `<a>`. For example it works fine in Chrome. You get the outline if you focus the link using TAB-key but no outline after having clicked the `<a>`  Thanks for the quick reply though.